# Fill a HTML select element with php, json and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

With below function I get data from the database:

```
public function cargarPaises(){
    $modelo = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
    $sql = "select idPais, nombre from paises";
    $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute();          
    return $statement;
}
```

Then in this other file I call the function "cargarPaises":

```
<?php

    require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
    require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

    $consultas = new Consultas();
    $datos = $consultas->cargarPaises();

    if (count($datos) > 0) {        
        while ($result = $datos->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            //printf ("%s (%s)\n", $result["idPais"], $result["nombre"]);echo"<br>";
            //return $result;
            //$nombre=$result['nombre'];
            //$idPais=$result['idPais'];            
            //echo "<option value=".$idPais.">".$nombre."</option>\n";
            //echo json_encode($result,JSON_HEX_QUOT | JSON_HEX_TAG | JSON_HEX_AMP | JSON_HEX_APOS);        
            echo json_encode($result);
        }                                   
    }else{
        return "No hay opciones en la BD";
    }

?>
```

Now when I try to use the code in a jquery file:

```
$('#email').click(function(event) {
        $.get('Controlador/cargarPaises.php', function(data) {      
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
```

I got the below in console (google chrome), All 427 records from my database (I am showing only 10):

```
echo json_encode($result); i got in console 

{"idPais":"1","nombre":"Mexico"}
{"idPais":"3","nombre":"Albania"}
{"idPais":"4","nombre":"Alemania"}
{"idPais":"5","nombre":"Andorra"}
{"idPais":"6","nombre":"Angola"}
{"idPais":"7","nombre":"Antigua y barbuda"}
{"idPais":"8","nombre":"Antillas holandesas"}
{"idPais":"10","nombre":"Argelia"}
```

Now the question is how can I "play" with the variable "data" to fill a select HTML element.

Comment: That wording at the end is seriously broad - you should consider rewording it so we know exactly what you're trying to achieve. For example, are you trying to convert the entire resultset into a table? Do you want to display the nombre for idPais 7, do you want to display the number of nombre's that start with an "A"?

Comment: i want to populate my html select element with the information which got the data variable, display the name and the value is the id

Comment: Edit your question to state that explicitly please :)

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have a bug in your cargarPaises file. You're echoing a json encoding of the object for each row - you probably actually want to return an array of objects as a single json result. You're also returning a string for an error rather than an object that would let you know that. And finally, you're getting the count of a PDO statement, rather than the rowCount. Something like this would be better:

```
if ($datos->rowCount() > 0) {       
    echo json_encode($datos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array());
}
```

I'd probably also modify your .get call for a start to explicitly state you're fetching json, and then add something like the following to build up the options:

```
$.get('Controlador/cargarPaises.php', function(data) {      
    $.each(data, function(idx, opt) {
        $('#myselect').append('<option value="' + opt.idPais + '">' + opt.nombre + '</option>');
    });
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function cargarPaises(){
    $modelo = new Conexion();
    $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
    $sql = "select idPais, nombre from paises where 1"; //changed
    $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  //changed    
}
```

And the second file

```
require_once('../Modelo/class.conexion.php');
require_once('../Modelo/class.consultas.php');

$consultas = new Consultas();
$datos = $consultas->cargarPaises();
$results = (count($datos) > 0) ? $datos : array("error"=>"No hay opciones en la BD");

echo json_encode($results);
```

Comment: why do you change the query?

Comment: To return all the data in the table

Comment: ok ty, now why if i change this line "return $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);" on te word fetchAll for only "fetch", then in the php file in the echo json_encode I received in screen the first register of my database but if i do leave "fetchAll" when i check for all the registers in the screen, don't show nothing?

Comment: I do not know exactly why I think of it as a series.